# Reference button object parameters programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing the authorisation framework for a GUI. A user logs in with valid credentials and is presented with the menu options (buttons) which the user has the permission to access.

I plan to show or hide the button visibility based on the permissions assigned to the user.

I am struggling to think of the best way to reference and toggle the button visibility programmatically. I have a List which details which menu items should be visible or not, but I don't know how to reference that list against the buttons on the form.

I can easily type the name of each button object and test against the list and toggle the visibility of the button, but this doesn't seem very efficient to me.

Code below. How best can I enable / disable button items?

```
class Menu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MenuItemFriendlyName { get; set; }
    public string ButtonName { get; set; }
    public bool Visable { get; set; }

    public List<Menu> CalculateMenuAccessForUser(User userDetails)
    {
        var menuItems = AllMenuItemsInSystem();

        foreach (var pt in userDetails.PermissionTable)
        {
            if(pt.Type != "Menu")
                break;

            if (menuItems.Exists(x => x.Id.Equals(pt.Id)))
            {
                var index = menuItems.FindIndex(y => y.Id.Equals(pt.Id));

                menuItems[index].Visable = true;
            }
        }

        return menuItems;
    }

    private List<Menu> AllMenuItemsInSystem()
    {
        var menu = new List<Menu>();

        using (var sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(Globals.AFWideSettings.SqlConnectionString))
        {
            sqlconnection.Open();
            using (
                var sqlcommand =
                    new SqlCommand("select name, permissionid from PermissionListTable where type = 'Menu'",
                                   sqlconnection))
            {
                var resultReader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (resultReader.Read())
                {
                    menu.Add(new Menu(){MenuItemFriendlyName = resultReader.GetString(0), Id = resultReader.GetInt32(1), Visable = false});
                }
            }
        }

        return menu;
    }
}

class Another{

    void BuildOutlookMenu()
    {
        var buildMenu = new Authentication.Menu();
        var menuBuilder = buildMenu.CalculateMenuAccessForUser(_userDetails);

        foreach (var menu in menuBuilder)
        {
            if (menu.Visable)
            {
                //Here I wish to enable or disable my menu buttons
                //BUTTON.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This post is probably better suited for Code Review

Comment: What container are you adding the buttons to? you could just create a `DataTemplate` for the `Menu` object that is based on `Button` with `Triggers` to handle the `Visibility` logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to associate each button to your Menu somehow, I probably would use the `Tag` Property to assign an Index to your Button, then create a List assign your Buttons to that, then iterate through it to determine wether to make it visible or not. You will need to associate the Buttons index with a property on your Menu Item(I used Tag as an example with the List named MenuButtons).

```
foreach (var menu in menuBuilder)
{
    if (menu.Visible)
    {
        Button result =  menuButtons.Find(btn => { return (int)btn.Tag == (int)menu.Tag;});
        if(result != null){result.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;}
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm obviously missing something here. How can I assign my existing button from my form to a List? Any attempt I make just creates a new button object in the list without any ability to reference the existing buttons.

Comment: @Damo The list will need to be a Class scoped variable, you will either need to use a foreach loop to add your buttons to the list or manually add them one at time. Once they are in the list they are still your buttons you are just using the list to find them.

Comment: Sorry, just figured it out. I was using the new keyword in my list rather than just referencing the button name directly. Works great now, thanks

Comment: @Damo Glad to be of help